# AspectJ Error: Could not find or load main class aop.HelloTest

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm learning aspectJ and met three questions. Why need to add all jar files to classpath but not only aspectjrt.jar(if just add one aspectjrt.jar file it will output `Could not find or load main class org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main`)? why i have already defined main class and using ajc compile successfully and then java packageName.MainClass error? error below:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class aop.HelloTest
```

Here is code:

```
package aop;   
 public class HelloTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.hello();// hello method just outout one word
    }
}

//aspectj class which under the same aop package, attention these two file are not in the same file.
public aspect AspectJTest {
    before(): execution(* aop.*.*(..)){
        System.out.println("stimulate authority check");
        }
}
```

Here is my work process:

```
ajc -d . *.java

java aop.HelloTest
```

Comment: `java -cp aspectjrt.jar aop.HelloTest` maybe?

Comment: Type `echo $CLASSPATH` output such jar file in terminal, totally believe `cp` will not work me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three jars in Aspectj:

- aspectjrt - the AspectJ runtime. A minimal jar containing classes typically used by woven code. You should run woven code with this jar on the classpath
- aspectjweaver - the AspectJ weaver. Should be used if attempting loadtime weaving.
- aspectjtools - the AspectJ compiler. Needs to be on your classpath if trying to run ajc.

The script `ajc` that launches the compiler will put aspectjtools on the classpath before invoking the compiler. Each jar above includes the contents of the earlier jar (so tools includes the compiler, weaver and runtime).  There is no 'runner' script so as Nandor mentions you need to ensure aspectjrt.jar is on the classpath before running your code, either via including it at launch time:

`java -cp aspectjrt.jar:. aop.HelloTest`

or set your classpath before invoking it:

`export CLASSPATH=<ASPECTJHOME>/lib/aspectjrt.jar:.`

`java aop.HelloTest`

Comment: Thank you Andy, my question resolved through your detail instruction. But here i still have one place not understand, why `-cp aspectj.jar:.`? what's the purpose of last point.

Comment: It ensures the current directory is on the classpath. Maybe not necessary in the case above as there is nothing to resolve there.